# converting an input date into a string?

Tags: python, string, date, input

I want to know how I can convert an input date for example if I enter 01/01/1996, the output would be "1 January 1996", I need to be able to do this for any date that is entered.
I need to use slicing.
Thank you in advance.

```
inLine = input("please enter a date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ").split(',') 
 monthNames = ("January", "February", "March", \
             "April", "May", "June", \
              "July", "August", "September", \
          "October", "November", "December" ) 
month = inLine [:10]
month2 = "month"[:1]
day = inLine
year = inLine[0:2]
year2 = "year"[0:4]
print("this is the date %s %s %s." % (month2, day2, year2))
```

Comment: and your code is in ?

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Is your 01/01/1996 month/day/year or day/month/year?

Comment: date=input('Enter a date(mm/dd/yyyy)')
replace=date.replace('/',' ')
convert = replace.split('/')
months = ("Janurary", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

day=convert[1:2]
year=convert[2:4]

print (months[convert[0]] + day + year)
this is what i go so far

Comment: please update your question with the code instead of a comment

Comment: updated the code 
if the users enters 05/05/2015
it should print 5 May 2015

Comment: Things to note... You're `split()`ing your input, which turns a string into an array of strings. You're then trying to slice the array (instead of slicing the input string). Also, `"month"[:1]` means the first character of the string `month` which will always be `m`. You probably mean `monthNames[month]`

Comment: Additionally all this is pointless unless you're just doing it for an exercise. Python already has built-in ways to change a string that represents a date into various objects within the date library.

Comment: it is for an exercise

Comment: I'd recommend yyyy/mm/dd, as it's way more clear, whenever possible (Munroe agrees: https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: @metaperture That standard is older than most people who ignore it...

Comment: @metaperture - If you're gonna go there... https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: That doesn't mean it's a bad idea. You also get the added benefit that string sorting in that format gives the same ordering as date sorting, which is incredibly useful, esp when you have some processing layers that are non-date-aware (e.g. filenames)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you need split your input when [datetime parsing libraries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) already exist in Python.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('01/01/1996', '%M/%d/%Y').strftime('%d %B %Y')
'01 January 1996'
```

Comment: Was just typing this! but yes, always use the standard libraries instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I would assume its being done as some kind of learning exercise?

Comment: for some reason i gotta do it with splitting

Comment: That reason is it's your homework, and you're just wanting someone to solve it for you. If you want to learn, learn. If you are trying to cheat, don't to it here.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simplistic response. You need to go away and learn about arrays, indexing and manipulating them. I also suggest, if this is homework of some kind, you go through and do more examples and look into what happens if, for example, I enter invalid input.

```
inLine = input("please enter a date (dd/mm/yyyy) : ").split('/') 
monthNames = ("January", "February", "March", \
             "April", "May", "June", \
              "July", "August", "September", \
          "October", "November", "December" ) 
day = int(inLine[0])
month = int(inLine[1])
year = int(inLine[2])

print("this is the date %s %s %s." % (day, monthNames[month-1], year))
```

Comment: Oh, and I recommend learning to debug you're original code - if you had, for example, added a few extra print() statements you would have seen exactly why your original code wasn't doing what you thought it was!

Comment: If OP needs splits, this way works (minus invalid input). Also, you don't need to cast day or year to an int.

Comment: I agree - its not necessary to cast anything but the month to an int. But I knocked it up as a crude example!